# Noise in audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, noise, proteus

I have built an audio amplifier using TDA2030. The amplifier works fine with very low noise, the input is given through 3.5mm jack of my phone. Everything works fine until I touch or pick up my **metal** phone, as I touch my phone the speaker starts giving out a loud noise until I place it back on the table.

Please tell me what is the cause of this noise, and how can I fix/reduce it.
[image: TDA2030]

Note: C1= 20uF in my circuit

**Edit:** It's a continuous buzz sound. It is the same type of noise we get when we touch an unplugged 3.5mm jack. I am providing power through a 12V 2Amp rated adapter (which is giving 18V output when not connected to load). I am using long wires to build the circuit. Actually, I used a breadboard to build the circuit and test it.

Many of you are suggesting that it's because of improper grounding. Please explain this because I am not getting your point, I will be happy to learn a new concept. And suggest a method to fix the noise.

Comment: Is your phone connected to the amp in any way? Are you hearing the GSM "dit-dit-dit" noise or something else like mains hum? Is your amplifier grounded? How is the amp powered? Add this info to the question.

Comment: *a loud noise* In engineering "noise" means a signal that sounds like "shshsh", a good example is an oldfashioned TV or radio that isn't tuned to any station. The typical signal I would expect when you touch an amplifier is called "hum", it sounds like Bzzzzz, a bit like a bee or other insect. What sound do you get? This amplifier is quite sensitive and you need to pay attention to proper grounding, this site has some tips: https://sound-au.com/earthing.htm also read this and follow the links mentioned in it: https://hifisonix.com/ground-loops/

Comment: Its a buzz sound like bees and other insects. It is the same type of noise we get when we touch an unplugged 3.5mm jack. I am providing power through a 12V 2Amp rated adapter (which is giving 18V output when not connected to load). I am using long wires to build the circuit. Actually, I used a breadboard to build the circuit and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the responses. But finally, I find a wonderful video that explains the exact solution to this and other noise-related problems.

https://youtu.be/xbinXh1ZSqk

Edit: The solution in the video is best, I tried it by myself and there is not even a single type of noise in the amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Bzzz or Hmmm and not a Shhhh (thanks to good input from a commenter) I think you have a classical ground loop.

When you touch your phone you form a loop from ground, via your feet to the phone to the amp and back to ground. This large loop captures significant EMI from the mains and other low frequency circuits.

You can confirm that it's not related to the phone by touching the unconnected amp inputs (e.g. at your 3.5mm audio jack when it is not plugged in to the phone). If you touch the ground ring you might hear a soft buzz, and when you touch the tip or middle ring (L/R signals) you'll hear a loud buzz.

To prevent this you have to isolate the amp input from any ground loops. A sub-100Hz decoupler could be all you need. Advanced audio equipment use a opto-coupler right at the input to prevent ground loops.

More: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=audio+ground+loop+isolator&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

This is a classical topic, and there are plenty of good videos and articles.

Comment: A ground loop would make sense if both the phone and the amp were on mains adaptors and the grounds would form a loop via protective earth. Note that phone chargers typically do not have PE connected in the wall socket (called safety class II device, here in the EU). But if the phone is running on battery, the only link being the audio cable, then it's not a ground loop. If the OP touches the metal chassis of the phone, and gets a loud SSHHHHH maybe with some pops mixed in, he may be facing RF oscillations. I've heard these happen with the TDA2040. Not enough clues though, in this case.

Comment: @frr he is touching the phone, that's one end of the loop, and the other is presumably via the amp's power supply.

Comment: In my understanding, a ground loop consists of sections of ground conductors, and the resistance around the loop is low units of ohms to milliohms. If the OP touches the phone (possible) and the amp's reference ground or chassis ground at the same time (unlikely), the electric resistance of that touch would be in kiloOhms.

Comment: I'm curious if something in the output of the amp could radiate electrostatic electricity, that could be picked up by a human touching the phone (comprising a good antenna for some RF band) - and re-introduced into the input of the TDA2030. Hence my theory about feedback-based oscillations.

Comment: @frr What can I do in that case. How to minimize RF oscillations?

Comment: I'm afraid that's a matter of PCB layout and mechanical engineering :-/ Would you dare to share some photoes with us? Your PCB layout, your mechanical chassis? Do you actually have an oscilloscope available? Could you maybe add a simple LC filter on the output and maybe input as well? Could you test at a lower power supply voltage? 18V is not much, but the amps are generally slower at lower Vcc = have less gain and less bandwidth, which makes them a little more stable. 100 nF parallel with 100 uF for power blocking doesn't look like much. How about say 2.2 - 10 milliFarad.

Comment: I can see the boucherot RC cell in your output. This can be expanded into a more comprehensive LC filter. Google DPA220 (switch to Images maybe) and take a look at its output filter. The inductor is just a few loops of enamel wire with a resistor placed axially inside - visible on the photoes :-) Keep tinkering. The journey is more important than the goal.

Comment: Currently, I am checking my circuit using a breadboard and long jumper wires.

Comment: @frr I noticed another thing right now, that it's not giving that noise when my feet are insulated ex. When I wear slippers? So, maybe it's because of ground loops. But how can I reduce it without using expensive techniques?

Comment: Keep your circuitry shielded. Add low-pass filters = RF blocks at input and output, so that cabling attached to those ports does not function as an antenna, so that the parasitic feedback loop loses gain. The electrostatic coupling is more significant at higher frequencies so that's what you need to suppress. Pay attention to PCB layout. Have one layer mostly filled with GND, make power traces short (no large loops), avoid large loops of cable. This is rather superficial and hypocritical advice, I know :-)

Comment: @Vishal If your amp is going to be battery powered, this might all go away or reduce significantly, but I would still put the filters in as at-frr suggests, because your body or chassis or any large object can pick-up low frequency EMI.

Comment: @P2000 I tried, but I am unable to break ground loops. I found this YouTube video helpful https://youtu.be/n_b_0BWP0mI but can you please explain to me how can I implement it in my circuit. I am really confused. Can you please explain how can I break/ isolate ground loops in my circuit. Thankyou

Comment: @frr After learning a lot about ground loops, I concluded that it is because of earth wire but I didn't connect the earth wire to my amp in any way only hot and neutral wire. So, what can be the other reason for the noise?  please correct me if I am wrong. I am really confused about this.

Comment: @Vishal: GreatScott = the guy in the YT vid clearly had a different problem than you have. BTW, in his case, I'd try to use blocking capacitors on the power line between the amp board and the BT receiver, and put the LM7805 as close to the BT receiver as possible, and block the resulting 5V rail too (difficult to say how much, as it's not very healthy to put large capacitors on output of these linear stabilizers) - anyway he had further options that he did not try. And this whole scenario is very different from yours, I guess.

Comment: @Vishal: I cannot see a ground loop in your topology. Your phone has its battery inside, and you have another battery for the amp. And if the noise in your case is like a loud SSHHHH, it's likely oscillations. The amp's input is picking up RF energy radiated by the amp's output. The resonant frequency of the loop is well above the audible range - the white/pink noise that you're hearing is just a demodulated envelope or average of some sort. These integrated audio amps have quite some gain well past the audio range. You need to minimize wiring loops in the power traces and input signal traces.

Comment: @Vishal: a tiny part of the energy, that your amp is feeding into the speaker, gets radiated into surrounding space (via static/capacitive coupling or inductive/magnetic coupling) and some part gets received into the amp's input. And gets amplified by the amp's gain. If the attenuation of the parasitic coupling is less than the gain of your amp, the signal will "pick up steam" in this endless parasitic feedback loop. (Theoretically there's also phase shift in the game... the "Nyquist stability criterion" applies.) The TDA2030 is stable on a dedicated PCB design, with minimized loops in traces.

Comment: @Vishal: GreatScott even did not have a ground loop. He just had a common ground that functioned as both an audio signal ground and a power supply return to device with "noisy consumption". Ground loops are yet a different problem :-)

Comment: @frr you are correct. I found exactly the same solution on YouTube (attached in the answer below). It is clearly parasitic oscillation, not a ground loop problem I think so. Thank you so much. This concept takes me a while to understand clearly.

Comment: @frr For the solution, I am going to attach all grounds directly to power ground.